# spring resource in WEB-INF

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean that has a property of type `File`. I want that property to end up pointing to a file under WEB-INF.

It seems to me that the `ServletContextResourceLoader` should have that job, somehow, but nothing I try seems to do the job.

I'm trying to avoid resorting to something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340744/how-to-acces-a-file-under-web-inf-from-a-java-web-application/3029239#3029239) in the Java code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that property has to remain as type "File", then you're going to have to jump through some hoops.

It would be better, if possible, to refactor the bean to have a `Resource` property, in which case you can inject the resource path as a String, and Spring will construct a `ServletContextResource` for you. You can then obtain the `File` from that using the `Resource.getFile()` method.

```
public class MyBean {

   private File file;

   public void setResource(Resource resource) {
      this.file = resource.getFile();
   }
}
```

---

```
<bean class="MyBean">
   <property name="resource" value="/WEB-INF/myfile">
</bean>
```

Comment: Oh, I expected Spring to have a default Resource editor that would take Resource to File via exactly your recipe. Silly me.

I can take your advice, though it then promptly runs into some trouble with the jetty-maven-plugin which is fodder for another question another day.

Comment: @bmargulies: If you try to inject a String value into a `File` property, then Spring will just convert directly to a `File` using `new File(String)`, which isn't what you need.